# In CNN, is it number of kernels/filters are same as neuron in each layer?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

For example:
if Layer 'L' of convnet contains only 8 kernel/filter, Which means in layer L there are only 8 neurons ?

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing between the word 'convolution filters' and 'neurons'. A convolution layer is different from fully-connected.

**Fully connected layer** do a mesh of weights multiplication between `nodes` or `neurons`. Each weight (the connection between each node) is updated via an optimizer.

**Convolution layer** learns filters (which is initialized randomly and also can be considered as weight). Its weights are also learned by an optimizer.

Comment: You mean there is no concept of neurons in Convolution layer ?

Comment: It's more like a kernel filter

Comment: Thanks for clarification, But one thing i would like to touch upon here is there is concept of neuron as well(at least indirectly if not directly). Each neuron will take portion of input image which is usually same size as kernel size and apply conv operation over selected portion of input image. Each neuron will focus on only  portion of input image and tries to learn insight form at that by applying n number of filters. These n of filter are shared by all the neurons in that layer .